# Listing data from database - use angularjs with API or generate using Jade on server-side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I'm creating a Node.js web app and I'm not sure whether to use AngularJS (or other client-side templating engine such as Ember or Backbone) to display data from a database or to generate the page on the server side (with Jade) and then send it over.  Is there a significant benefit to using one approach versus the other?

Angular does add an extra layer of complexity, but at the same time I'm concerned about the performance detriments involved when generating pages on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use both jade and angularjs. yes jade render the page at server side and angular at client side. The reason behind using the both is to render the index view or say first landing view, where our angular `ui-view`  directive and our application js or css files are included should be render with jade. after that angular will take care of all others routes.

```
    extends layout

block base 
  base(href="#{base_url}")
block content

  #Main(ng-app="your-angaulr-app")

      div(ui-view)
        p Load App Here

    var bootstrap = !{JSON.stringify(bootstrap)}; 
  script(src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
  script(src="/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js")

  script(src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js")
  script(src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js")
  script(src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js")

  script(src="/js/build/application.js")
  script(src="/js/build/admin-templates.js")
```

this is the index.jade file you should render from jade after that angular will do his work.

Comment: What is /js/build/admin-templates.js for?

Comment: Its just cache of html file in my project. May be different in you case its just for performance

Comment: Oh,ok.  Quick jade question - if you write #main, it automatically compiles to <div id='main'></div>?

Comment: Yes you got the point

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to show some data from a DB , then you are probably better off using Server side code. Otherwise the user has to wait for two HTTP Get operations to complete before seeing any results. First one loading the empty page with JS files,and the second one fetching the data. not to mention all the .js files needed to be loaded to browser and extra code you have to write.

But if your data needs to be updated without refreshing the whole page (by user interactions or updates from server) then you should look at client side code and frameworks. Angular allows you to implement MVC pattern on client side which has many benefits, but as you said it may look like it is also adding some complexity.

Comment: I need to show a list of something from a DB, then lazy load as the user scrolls down.  Would Angular work for this?  I'm also open to using other frameworks such as Backbone or Ember.